# Why webpack code splitting doesnot work as expected?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want `jquery` globally available and `.js/uploader.js` only evaluated at `/login` on demand. This is what I try:

index.js

```
require("./css/main.scss")
$ = require("jquery")
require.ensure(["./js/uploader"], function(require) {
    if (window.location.pathname=='/login') {
        var uploader = require("./js/uploader")
    }
});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: '../wdksw/static/js',
        publicPath: 'static/js/', 
        filename: "bundle.js", 
    }, 
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }, 
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]}, 
        ], 

    }
};
```

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I make a request that is not `/login` in browser the `1.bundle.js` is also requestd, this is not what I want. So, what should I do? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `require.ensure` should be in `if` statement:

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/login') {
    require.ensure(["./js/uploader"], function(require) {
        var uploader = require("./js/uploader")
    });
}
```

Now your bundle will be added to your head only on matched condition in `if` statement.

Comment: During the waiting time I come up the idea the same with you.  It works. I just wonder is it a standart way or is there some plungins for this?

Comment: Dynamic importing code like `require.ensure` is still evolving. Just look on `System.import` from webpack 2. Your use case is looking good - you don't need any plugin more than weback can give you.